# If I'm making an engineering drawing for a machinist, how do I define the undercut of a gear?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears

The drawing is of a small gear with an involute curve turning into a trochoid root causing an undercut. How do I define the undercut of this gear for a machinist?

[image]

Comment: Picture missing?

Comment: new picture now @Drew

Comment: If it's for low quantity cnc with almost no hope of QC anyway, give 'em a dxf (2D) or other CAD file.